# How to Remove Minimum Value from a Data frame

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning, feature-engineering

I'm a novice in Data Science, but I think I have a doubt here.
I have attached the image below.

[Image of Described one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CCpg.png)

In the Dataframe above in the Columns ===> the Humidity, Wind Speed (km/h), Visibility (km), and Pressure (millibars), there are min values which are zero. I don't feel that they should be zero, if am right how can I replace those min values with the next min value using pandas in my data frame. Or please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, following will do the trick:

```
cols = ['Humidity','Wind Speed (km/h)', 'Visibility (km)', 'Pressure (millibars)']
df_train.loc[:, cols] = df_train.loc[:,cols].apply(lambda X: applymin(X))
```

where `applymin(X)`

```
def applymin(X):
    X[X==X.min()] = sorted(X.unique().tolist())[1]
    return X
```

i.e. wherever a column is minimum, we replace it by 2nd smallest value.